# NTLM Authentication using RestSharp?

Tags: ntlm, restsharp, teamcity-7.1

I am trying to use NTLM authentication for my REST calls to TeamCity using RestSharp.

```
IRestClient _client=new RestClient(_url);
_client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator            
(System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
```

However it is not working. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: How to implement the same using jQuery ajax? I want to consume a rest service which is in.. svc format, and fetch the json data..

Answer (score 42):

This now appears to be working properly and can be done very easily utilizing the [NTLMAuthenticator](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Authenticators/NtlmAuthenticator.cs) like so:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(_baseURL);
client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
```

Comment: If you use this method don't forget to add a `using RestSharp.Authenticators;` line.

Comment: no longer works in RestSharp 1.07+, I switched to System.Net.WebClient due to the frustration this caused

Comment: @Ekus Could you have used the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069138/470014 by Alemayehu Tessera instead?

Comment: @Caltor perhaps. Not sure if I'd seen it back then, plus when a helper library mutates or requires different steps that were not needed previously, in my small project it made sense to just do it manually without the library.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
var client = new RestClient(_baseURL)
{
     Authenticator = new RestSharp.Authenticators.NtlmAuthenticator()
};
```

Answer (score 7):

As of RestSharp v107, [The NtlmAuthenticator is deprecated](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/0ac3035e9696eaac957dbb8679cc07d1913333d0/docs/v107/README.md#ntlm-authentication).

This worked for me:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
var options = new RestClientOptions(_settings.ServiceEndPoint)
{
 UseDefaultCredentials = false,
 Credentials=credentials
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not supported currently. Refer to the below thread.

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/451079?tstart=0